# What is the sub-differential of L2 norm?

Tags: abstract-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis

I need to drive the sub-differential of L2 norm of a vector. Would someone can help me with this ?

Comment: Why is it marked as off topic? I don't understand, finding derivative and integrals are on topic and finding sub-differential is off-topic. Down voting because of lack of context make sense but why put on hold as off-topic?

Comment: Wikipedia shows the derivative for $x\neq 0$: $x / ||x||$. For $x=0$, $0$ is a subdifferential (readily verified with the definition).